# calculator logic

Tags: javascript, calculator

How can I rewrite this if statement of which there are a lot. Or how, in principle, it can be rewritten to look good? This app is calculator. How it can be redone with a switch maybe. Or breaking it somehow into small functions

````
function pressNumber(e) {
  let digit;
  
  if (typeof e === 'string') {
    digit = e;
  } else {
    digit = e.target.innerText;
  }

  if (isHistoryOperator(history.innerText.length - 1) && input.innerText !== '-') {
    input.innerText = '';
  }

  if (equalsPressed()) {
    history.innerText = digit;
    input.innerText = digit;
  } else if (isHistoryTooLong() || isInputTooLong()) {
    return;
  } else if (input.innerText === '0' || input.innerText === '-0') {
    history.innerText = history.innerText.slice(0, history.innerText.length - 1) + digit;
    if (input.innerText === '0') {
      input.innerText = digit;
    } else {
      input.innerText = '-' + digit;
    }
  } else {
    history.innerText += digit;
    input.innerText += digit;
  }
}

function pressDecimal() {
  if (equalsPressed() || input.innerText === '') {
    history.innerText = '0.';
    input.innerText = '0.';
    return;
  }

  if (isHistoryOperator(history.innerText.length - 1) && input.innerText !== '-') {
    input.innerText = '';
  }

  if (isHistoryTooLong() || isInputTooLong() || input.innerText.includes('.')) {
    return;
  } else if (isHistoryOperator(history.innerText.length - 1)) {
    history.innerText += '0.';
    input.innerText += '0.';
  } else if (history.innerText[history.innerText.length - 1] !== '.') {
    history.innerText += '.';
    input.innerText += '.';
  }
}

function pressOperator(e) {
  let operator = e;
  if (e === '-' && (isHistoryOperator(history.innerText.length - 1) || history.innerText === '')) {
    pressPlusMinus();
    return;
  }

  if (
    history.innerText === '' ||
    input.innerText.search(/[a-z><]/gi) !== -1 ||
    (isHistoryOperator(history.innerText.length - 1) && isHistoryOperator(history.innerText.length - 2))
  ) {
    return;
  }

  if (typeof e === 'string') {
    operator = e;
  } else {
    operator = e.target.innerText;
  }

  if (equalsPressed()) {
    history.innerText = input.innerText + operator;
  } else if (isHistoryTooLong()) {
    return;
  } else if (isHistoryOperator(history.innerText.length - 1)) {
    history.innerText = history.innerText.slice(0, history.innerText.length - 1) + operator;
  } else {
    history.innerText += operator;
  }
}

function pressBackspace() {
  if (history.innerText.search(/[a-z><]/gi) !== -1) {
    input.innerText = '';
    history.innerText = '';
    return;
  }

  if (history.innerText === '') {
    return;
  }

  if ((!isHistoryOperator(history.innerText.length - 1) || input.innerText === '-') && !equalsPressed()) {
    input.innerText = input.innerText.slice(0, input.innerText.length - 1);
  } else {
    input.innerText = lastNoInHistory();
  }

  history.innerText = history.innerText.slice(0, history.innerText.length - 1);
}

function pressPlusMinus() {
  if (equalsPressed() && !input.innerText.includes('-')) {
    let historyIndex = history.innerText.lastIndexOf(input.innerText);
    input.innerText = '-' + input.innerText;
    history.innerText = history.innerText.slice(0, historyIndex) + input.innerText;
  } else if (isHistoryTooLong() || isInputTooLong()) {
    return;
  } else if (history.innerText === '-') {
    input.innerText = '';
    history.innerText = '';
  } else if (isHistoryOperator(history.innerText.length - 1) && !isHistoryOperator(history.innerText.length - 2)) {
    input.innerText = '-';
    history.innerText += '-';
  } else if (!input.innerText.includes('-')) {
    let historyIndex = history.innerText.lastIndexOf(input.innerText);
    input.innerText = '-' + input.innerText;
    history.innerText = history.innerText.slice(0, historyIndex) + input.innerText;
  } else {
    let historyIndex = history.innerText.lastIndexOf(input.innerText);
    input.innerText = input.innerText.slice(1);
    history.innerText = history.innerText.slice(0, historyIndex) + input.innerText;
  }
}

function pressEquals() {
  if (isHistoryOperator(history.innerText.length - 1) ||
    history.innerText[history.innerText.length - 1] === '=' ||
    history.innerText === ''
  ) {
    return;
  }

  let numbersArray = history.innerText.split(/[^0-9.]+/g).filter(i => i !== '');
  numbersArray = numbersArray.map(i => Number(i));
  const operatorsArray = history.innerText.split(/[0-9.]+/g).filter(op => op !== '');

  if (history.innerText[0] === '-') {
    numbersArray[0] = -numbersArray[0];
    operatorsArray.shift();
  }

  history.innerText += '=';
  input.innerText = evaluate(numbersArray, operatorsArray).toString();
}

function evaluate(numbersArray, operatorsArray) {
  for (let i = 0; i < operatorsArray.length; i++) {
    if (operatorsArray[i][0] === '\xF7' || operatorsArray[i][0] === '\xD7') {
      let evaluation = simpleEval(numbersArray[i], numbersArray[i + 1], operatorsArray[i]);
      numbersArray.splice(i, 2, evaluation);
      operatorsArray.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < operatorsArray.length; i++) {
    let evaluation = simpleEval(numbersArray[i], numbersArray[i + 1], operatorsArray[i]);
    numbersArray.splice(i, 2, evaluation);
    operatorsArray.splice(i, 1);
    i--;
  }

  return output(numbersArray[0]);

  function simpleEval(a, b, operation) {
    switch (operation) {
      case '+':
        return a + b;
      ....
    }
  }

  function output(n) {
    if (Math.abs(n) < 1) {
      return Number(n.toPrecision(8)).toString();
    } else if (n > 9999999999 && Math.abs(n) !== Infinity) {
      return '>9999999999';
    } else if (n < -999999999 && Math.abs(n) !== Infinity) {
      return '<-999999999';
    } else if (
      !Number(n.toPrecision(9))
        .toString()
        .includes('.')
    ) {
      return Number(n.toPrecision(10)).toString();
    }
    return Number(n.toPrecision(9)).toString();
  }
}

function isHistoryOperator(i) {
  return (
    history.innerText[i] === '+' ||
    history.innerText[i] === '\xF7' ||
    history.innerText[i] === '\xD7' ||
    history.innerText[i] === '-'
  );
}

function equalsPressed() {
  return history.innerText[history.innerText.length - 1] === '=' || history.innerText === '';
}

function isHistoryTooLong() {
  return history.innerText.length > 20;
}

function isInputTooLong() {
  return input.innerText.length >= 10;
}

function lastNoInHistory() {
  let number = history.innerText
    .split(/[^0-9.]+/g)
    .filter(i => i !== '')
    .pop();

  if (history.innerText.endsWith('-' + number, history.innerText.length - 1)) {
    number = '-' + number;
  }

  return number;
}

```
````

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/249471/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: Do you have any working examples of the code?